# Excel to Access Changing Data Type

Tags: excel, date, ms-access, text, import

I am in a pickle. I need to replace previous data with new data in Access. I am importing the data as an Excel file. Unfortunately, one of the fields is being changed from Date to Text.

When I import the data it is showing up as "Date With Time" in the Import Spreadsheet Wizard.  It is formatted in Excel as Short Date.

In smaller data sets I have been able to change the Data Type to "Date/Time". Unfortunately, I get a message stating that "Microsoft Access can't change the data type. There isn't enough disk space or memory".

Answer (score 0):

You can do an update query and format your text field as a date field.
e.g.

```
Format([FieldName], "dd/mm/yyyy")
```